# How to send text from DataOutputStream to a TextField on JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx

I'm building up a Chat Application using JavaFX but I can't figure out how to send the String from DataOutputStream to my TextField.

I was able to write my code using JFrame, but I want to do it using Java FX, however I can't access my TextField from another pane. Any Suggestions?

```
//Creating Center Pane
        public FlowPane getFlowPane2() {
            FlowPane centerPane = new FlowPane();
            centerPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            centerPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            centerPane.setHgap(5.5);
            centerPane.setVgap(5.5);

           //Creating the node inside Top Pane (TextArea)
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            textField.setPromptText("Type your message here");
            textField.setPrefColumnCount(40);
            textField.setText(""); 

            //Placing node inside Top Pane
            centerPane.getChildren().add(textField);
            return centerPane;
        }

        //Creating Bottom Pane
        public HBox getHBox() {
        HBox hBox = new HBox(15);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        //Creating Nodes inside the pane (Buttons)
        Button send = new Button("Send");
        send.setOnAction((event) -> {
            try {
        String msgout = "";
        msgout = textField.setText(); //My error is here. I can't access my textField from here
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        });
        Button exit = new Button("Exit");
        exit.setOnAction(this);
```

I expect to send the String from my DataOutputStream to my textfield, which will be showing messages from a Chat Applicationm

Comment: You've defined `textField` within the `getFlowPane2()` method; it will not be accessible outside of that method. Perhaps a [mcve] would be helpful here (as they **always** are when asking for help with coding errors)...

Comment: taking your code literally, looks like it's time for reading a basic tutorial on java and fx: trying to set the return value of a setter (which is void) to a string is bound to be blow (at compile time already). But then, maybe it's a typo .. so please follow @Zephyr 's suggestion, without doing so, your question is likely to be closed as not answerable